# How to Store JWT Token to Cookies and use it for authentication

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt

So i'm making a simple games store app that has a login/register function, an index page with games to "buy", a page for the user to see the games they have bought and a chart that will help users buy good games. I managed to make my login and register functions to work, it's also creating a token for the user and i want that token to be stored to cookies when a user logs and then when redirecting to the index page it verifies the token stored on cookies to allow the user in, and that's the problem, the token is being stored on cookies but it says my req.cookies.token is undefined so it keeps giving me an error message instead of redirecting to the index page, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong

this is my authorization service

```
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require("dotenv-safe").config();

exports.authorize = function(req, res, next){
    const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.cookies.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
    console.log(req.cookies.token);
    if (!token){
        res.status(401).json({auth: false, message: 'You need to Login to access this page.'});
    } else {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, function (error, decode){
            if (error){
                res.status(401).json({auth: false, message: 'Invalid Token.'});
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my login function

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
require("dotenv-safe").config();

exports.login = async(mail, pass) => {    
    const user = await Usuario.findOne({ email: mail });
    const id = user._id;
    if (user.email === mail && user.ValidPassword(pass)){
        const token = jwt.sign({id}, process.env.SECRET, {expiresIn: 18000}); //5 min
        return res.cookie('x-access-token', token, { secure: false, httpOnly: true});
        return token;
    } else{
        throw({status: 404, code: 'User not Found.', message: 'Try another E-mail.'});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it now, i guess i was sending the token to cookies in the wrong place, i changed the following in my auth.service:

```
exports.authorize = function(req, res, next){
const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.cookies['x-access-token'] || req.headers['x-access-token'];
```